# Limit of $F_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor)$ where $ F_{n}(k)=G_{n}(k)+H_{n}(k)F_{n}(k+1) $ and $F_{n}(n)=\mu.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

The following conjecture is inspired by asymptotic results in generalizations of the secretary problem.

CONJECTURE
Consider a sequence of functions {$F_n$} with $F_{n}:[0,n]\cap
\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined recursively, for $k\in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, by the
conditions:
$$F_{n}(k)=G_{n}(k)+H_{n}(k)F_{n}(k+1)\text{ and }F_{n}(n)=\mu.$$
Let $f_{n}(x):=F_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor)$, $h_{n}(x):=n(1-H_{n}(\lfloor
{nx}\rfloor))$ and $g_{n}(x):=nG_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor)$. If both $h_{n}(x)$
and $g_{n}(x)$ converge in $(0,1)$ and uniformly in $[\varepsilon
,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$ to
continuous functions in $(0,1)$, $h(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively, then
$f_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly in $[\varepsilon
,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$ with $f\in \mathcal{C}^1(0,1)$ and $f$ satisfies the following differential equation in $(0,1)$
$$f^{\prime}(x)= f(x)h(x)-g(x).$$

Example (secretary problem):

$$F_{n}(k)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{k}{k+1}F_{n}(k+1)\text{ and }F_{n}(n)=0.$$
$$F_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor) \rightarrow -x \log(x) $$
The associated differential equation is:
$$f^{\prime}(x)= \frac{f(x)}{x}-1 \Rightarrow f(x)=xC-x \log(x)$$

For n=10,50,100 and 1000$; F_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor) \rightarrow -x \log(x) $

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3So5B.png) Ribas, J.M.G. A new look at the returning secretary problem. J Comb Optim 37, 1216–1236 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10878-018-0349-8

[2] Bayón, L., Fortuny Ayuso, P., Grau, J.M. et al. A New Method for Computing Asymptotic Results in Optimal Stopping Problems. Bull. Malays. Math. Sci. Soc. 46, 46 (2023). https://doi.org/10.1007/s40840-022-01436-4

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the uniform convergence in $[\varepsilon
,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$
is a too weak condition for the conclusion.
For instance, let for each natural $k<n$ we have $G_n(k)=0$ and $H_n(k)=1$, but the case $H_n(n-1)=n$.
Then $F_n(k)=\mu n$. Then both $h_{n}(x)$
and $g_{n}(x)$ converge in $(0,1)$ and uniformly in $[\varepsilon
,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$ to the zero function,
but even the sequence $(f_n(1/2))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. OKAY!. I notice that I forgot the condition $|H_n(k)|≤1$ and  $|G_n(k)|≤cons.$
 In that case, what do you think?

Comment: @JoséMaríaGrauRibas We can modify the above example by putting $\mu\ne 0$ and $H_n(n-1)=(-1)^n$. Then $F_n(k)=(-1)^n\mu$, so the sequence $(f_n(1/2))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ diverges.